# How can i get my rds-ca-2019 pem file from AWS RDS Amazon

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, certificate, amazon-rds

I have an RDS I have created with AWS of type postgresql

Under connectivity, i as see it defined a **rds-ca-2019**
I need that certificate for connection from a Java client application
I tried using global pem, but it seems not to match and failing on SSL connection
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.SSL.html

Where can i get this  **rds-ca-2019** certificate

[image]

Comment: The link you posted specifies exactly where to download rds certificates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The download resource i was looking can be found as below in the attacked link

https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en_us/articles/amazon-lightsail-download-ssl-certificate-for-managed-database

Answer (score 3):

Here is the 2019 aws rds root cert
https://s3.amazonaws.com/rds-downloads/rds-ca-2019-root.pem